# send text message and html table both as message body using mailr package in R

Tags: r

```
send.mail(from = "abc@gmail.com",
          to = c("abc@gmail.com"),
          subject = mail_subject,
          body = "High_loss_gain_Imprsn_accounts.html",
          html=TRUE,
          attach.files = "c:/users/rkathuria/Documents/ACCOUNT_BLOCK_NO_COST_MONITOR.xlsx",
          smtp = list(host.name = "aspmx.l.google.com", port = 25),
          authenticate = FALSE,
          send = TRUE)
```

In the body part of `send.mail;` i want to send this html table and a "Hello" message. However, it is either taking my message or html table.

`body = "High_loss_gain_Imprsn_accounts.html"` ----> this line prints my table in mail message body.
`body = "Hello"` --> this lines prints Hello.

How can I put together in mail body?
<------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
If instead of xtable, i use tableHTML package and write my code, would it will solve my purpose of adding 2 tables on mail with subject.

```
mail_body1<-tableHTML(High_loss_gain_Imprsn_accounts, widths = rep(100, 11), caption="Hi, High gain loss account", collapse = 'separate')
mail_body<-paste0(mail_body1,mail_body1)
mail_subject<-paste("Account Block No Cost Monitor ", Sys.Date()-1)

send.mail(from = "abc@gmail.com",
          to = c("abc@gmail.com"),
          subject = mail_subject,
          body = mail_body,
          html=TRUE,
          attach.files = "c:/users/rkathuria/Documents/ACCOUNT_BLOCK_NO_COST_MONITOR.xlsx",
          smtp = list(host.name = "aspmx.l.google.com", port = 25, ssl = TRUE),
          authenticate = FALSE,
      send = TRUE)
```

And new problem am facing is through this smtp, mail is not going now.

Answer (score 0):

I struggeled with this before and the best solution I could find was using `xtable` to produce a html table with caption:

```
table <- data.frame(a = LETTERS[1:6],
           b = LETTERS[7:12])
mailR::send.mail(from = "XXXXXXXX",
                 to = "XXXXXXXX",
                 subject = "Hello World",
                 body = xtable::print.xtable(xtable::xtable(table, 
                                                            caption = "Hello World"), 
                                             type = "html", 
                                             caption.placement = "top",
                                             include.rownames = FALSE),
                 html = TRUE,
                 smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", 
                             port = 465, 
                             user.name = "XXXXXXXX",            
                             passwd = "XXXXXXXX", 
                             ssl = TRUE),
                 authenticate = TRUE,
                 send = TRUE)
```

The problem is that you can only pass one object or path to `body`. So if you want to have more than one caption line, you would need to change your html object, I think (I haven't tested what happens if you put more text into the caption, so this might work, too).